# How to get maven version in Jenkins email notification when using emailext

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-email-ext

How to get maven version in Jenkins email notification using emailext. I need to print the maven version, project is using, in the email notification.
Please suggest.

Comment: I have tried using variable $POM_VERSION in emailext as well as in the groovy email template under JENKINS_HOME/email-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below code to my groovy email template. It worked, fetched the maven version from the project pom in the email.

```
<%  def variable = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("/var/jenkins_home/jobs/projectName/pom.xml"))
       def param = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("MAVEN_VERSION", variable.prerequisites.maven.toString())
       def version = param.getValue() %>
<tr>
      <td>Maven:</td>
      <td>${version}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting this right ,you can simply run the command and put it in a varible and use it in the text you are sending. eg.

```
mvnVersion = sh (
                  script: "mvn -version",
                  returnStdout: true
            ).trim()

emailText = "this is the mvn version - ${mvnVersion}"
```

if you want any specific information you can always use replaceAll() to get it .

Comment: are you suggesting me to run the above command from inside groovy email template?

Comment: Yes just send the emailText in the email body , you can check what it gets by printing mvnVersion and see the output and extract what is necessary .

Comment: It throws error: [Could not find content token (check your usage): sh]

Comment: can you post a screenshot